# Let floats appear out of order

Tags: floats

Is it possible for floats (the figure environment) appear out of order? In my case I have a figure that takes up a whole page, followed quickly by one that is maybe a third of the page. If they are both called on page 1, the whole-page figure appears on page 2, and the smaller figure appears on page 3, long after I've stopped referencing it. I'd like to the smaller figure to appear on page 1 if adequate room exists.

Comment: anything is possible but basically no. The number is already typeset in the box at the point the figure is encoutered so you really can't re-number them. Printing them out of order is possible but the entire float mechanism is designed to keep floats in order. The simplest way would be to put one in a figure and one in a table but use `\captionof{figure}` instead of `\caption` then they can float past each other. (`capt-of` or `caption`  packages for `\captionof`)

Comment: why can't you simply move the smaller figure in the source to be first?

Comment: To familiarize yourself with LaTeX's float placement algorithm, you may want to consult the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001) and especially [Frank Mittelbach's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5001).

Comment: Or you can define a different type of float, say `bigfigure`, but then they needs to be numbered differently. I have somewhere `figure` for my exams and `extrafigure` for when I typeset the solution...

Comment: Somewhat related, but overkill:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230152/float-placement-on

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I want the larger figure first because it comes first in the document I'm describing (a piece of music). I'll try the \captionof option, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your comment, you say you want the larger figure first but the question is all about making the smaller one come first isn't it?

Comment: I meant that I refer to the larger figure first in the text, so it makes sense for it to have the lower figure number. I could put the definition for the smaller figure first, but the numbering would be odd.