# Specifying positions of floats exactly (e.g. top of right hand column of page 2)

Tags: floats

Short version: how can I disable LaTeX's automatic figure placement and instead specify their positions manually, relative to the page layout rather than their position in the text?

Long version: Once I've finished writing a document I often have to do a lot of fiddling to get the figures where I want them. (This happens especially when there's a page limit, e.g. for a conference paper.) Typically this involves a lot of trial-and-error moving of the `figure` environments in the document source, as well as editing the captions and rescaling the figures etc. in order to try and coax them into the right places. This process is inefficient and I'm wondering if there might be a better way.

Specifically, I'm wondering if there's a way to specify the figures' positions directly, without using LaTeX's automatic positioning. I still want them to appear as floating figures in the document, but I want to say exactly where they belong, e.g. at the top of the right hand column on page 2. Is this possible?

Here's an MWE. The goal is to position the two figures at the top of the right-hand column on the second page, regardless of where they appear in the source document.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

% this figure should appear at the top of the right-hand column on page 2, *no matter what*.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A figure.}
\end{figure}

% this figure should appear at the top of the right-hand column on page 2, underneath the
% first figure, no matter what.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Another figure.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking around there's an obvious way to (ab)use the feature of using non-float [floats - Force figure placement in text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text?noredirect=1&lq=1) then put it at the exact place where TeX break the line... which may work. // there's also [positioning - Forcing a table or image on a specified page - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95022/forcing-a-table-or-image-on-a-specified-page)

Comment: @user202729 thank you! That second link is promising - I might play around with it later and see if I can come up with a workable system based on that approach. (I don't know if it will work in a multicolumn setting but will try to figure it out. I also don't know if it will respect the style file in terms of the font for the caption etc., but I can experiment with that.) I think the first idea probably won't work very well - it might require placing the `figure` environment in the middle of a hyphenated word, for example.

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673406/placing-a-figure-on-specific-page-in-output-pdf/674402#674402 essentially

Comment: I doubt it will save  work, but if you are very sure about the final document layout  you could use the static frames from the `flowfram` package for the figures.  An example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73572/11604).